# Why if statement not correct in batch file

Tags: string, batch-file, if-statement

I wrote a short code in .bat file - but I get an error that the if command is incorrect.

my code:

```
@echo off
set arg1=%1
echo %arg1%
if %arg1% == rot(
echo yes)
```

the output is:

> rot
>
> The syntax of the command is incorrect.

When I looked for the way to write if statement in bat file I saw lots of syntax options but non of them works for me.
I tried:

```
if "%arg1%" == rot
if "%arg1%" == "rot"
if %arg1% == "rot"
```

But no one was ok.

I Will be very happy to get help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code must look like:

```
@echo off
set arg1=%1
echo %arg1%
IF "%arg1%" == "rot" (
  echo yes
)
```

both arguments must be in double quotes:

```
test.bat rot
rot
yes
```

Comment: I did it and I get the same error rot
**The syntax of the command is incorrect.**

Comment: @STF for me it works fine. you have used exactly my code?

Comment: I copied your code and now it's good - I changed the if to IF but I don't think that the "if" was the problem. Thanks!

Comment: The problem is actually that the `(` must be separated from the comparison-string otherwise it appears to be part of the string to be compared and then `if` complains that there's nothing specified to be done. The quotes are optional, but a good idea whenever there's a possibility that the arguments contain separators like spaces.